# What do I mean? Listen to the clues

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

Let me start off with two long clues:

> There is nothing here560378

there is a secret Text yo^u^ mus4t decipher from my writing. scan every word carefully so+that+you don't m3iss any information. {go}od luck.

> There is nothing here342013

there is tHe va5lley(or was a valley9), In the valley Sings a swin*g a(n)d sings  a songberd. the bird that sung was a swan,

> There is nothing here392050

nExt to tHe valley was a frog pond, the frog pond was large, i like that frog pond,

> There is nothing here907768

then there was nothing more,

---

**Hints:**

Hint 1

> There is a very common code in use here, beware of the red herrings!

Hint 2

> Two words from the first line are very important

Hint 3

> The answer is a single word

Hint 4

> Ignore what the cypher tells you to

Comment: "Let me start off with two long clues" So one clue is the quoted text and one the unquoted? Also, with some characters with capitals and others not (i.e. `nExt to tHe valley`), it most likely has a meaning. In that regard I hope there aren't a lot of typos/grammar errors in the text. :) By which I mean, are there reasons for: (part 1) The word `scan` not starting with a capital `S` at the start of a sentence; (part 2) The word `In` starting with a capital `I` after a comma and `the` not starting with a capital `T` at the start of a sentence; (part 3) `i like` not being with a capital `I`; etc.

Comment: I have checked over and there a no typos.

Comment: Perhaps a hint is in order?

Comment: Alright i'll give you all second hint

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> If you take all the mistakes and brackets out and put them together they make this: T^^4++3{} H59IS*() EH

Comment: Please use spoiler formatting (>!) when answering questions.

Comment: And what does that mean? Or is this just a partial answer?